# unix socket error 14: EFAULT (bad address)

Tags: c, sockets, udp, sendto

I have a very simple question, but I have not managed to find any answers to it all weekend. I am using the `sendto()` function and it is returning error code 14: EFAULT. The man pages describe it as:

```
"An invalid user space address was specified for an argument."
```

I was convinced that this was talking about the IP address I was specifying, but now I suspect it may be the *memory* address of the message buffer that it is referring to - I can't find any clarification on this anywhere, can anyone clear this up?

Comment: something inside the `const struct msghdr *message` argument you gave to sendmsg is invalid, post some relevant code if you want help on more specifics.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`EFAULT` It happen if the memory address of some argument passed to `sendto` (or more generally to any system call) is invalid. Think of it as a sort of `SIGSEGV` in kernel land regarding your syscall. For instance, if you pass a null or invalid buffer pointer (for reading, writing, sending, recieving...), you get that

See [errno(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/errno), [sendto(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto) etc... man pages.

`EFAULT` is not related to IP addresses at all.

Comment: Aha okay thankyou, i'll check my buffer pointer when I get home and see if thats fixes it!

Comment: yep, that did it! I had got some of my pointers confused, thankyou!

Answer (score 4):

**Minimal runnable example with `getcpu`**

Just to make things more concrete, we can have a look at the `getcpu` system call, which is very simple to understand, and shows the same EFAULT behaviour.

From `man getcpu` we see that the signature is:

```
int getcpu(unsigned *cpu, unsigned *node, struct getcpu_cache *tcache);
```

and the memory pointed to by the `cpu` will contain the ID of the current CPU the process is running on after the syscall, the only possible error being:

```
ERRORS
       EFAULT Arguments point outside the calling process's address space.
```

So we can test it out with:

main.c

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

int main(void) {
    int err, ret;
    unsigned cpu;

    /* Correct operation. */
    assert(syscall(SYS_getcpu, &cpu, NULL, NULL) == 0);
    printf("%u\n", cpu);

    /* Bad trash address == 1. */
    ret = syscall(SYS_getcpu, 1, NULL, NULL);
    err = errno;
    assert(ret == -1);
    printf("%d\n", err);
    perror("getcpu");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

compile and run:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.out main.c
./main.out
```

Sample output:

```
cpu 3
errno 14
getcpu: Bad address
```

so we see that the bad call with a trash address of `1` returned `14`, which is EFAULT as seen from kernel code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53958705/895245

Remember that the syscall itself returns `-14`, and then the `syscall` C wrapper detects that it is an error due to being negative, returns `-1`, and sets `errno` to the actual precise error code.

And since the syscall is so simple, we can confirm this from the kernel 5.4 implementation as well at [`kernel/sys.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.4/kernel/sys.c#L2496):

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(getcpu, unsigned __user *, cpup, unsigned __user *, nodep,
        struct getcpu_cache __user *, unused)
{
    int err = 0;
    int cpu = raw_smp_processor_id();

    if (cpup)
        err |= put_user(cpu, cpup);
    if (nodep)
        err |= put_user(cpu_to_node(cpu), nodep);
    return err ? -EFAULT : 0;
}
```

so clearly we see that `-EFAULT` is returned if there is a problem with `put_user`.

It is worth mentioning that my glibc does have a `getcpu` wrapper as well in `sched.h`, but that implementation segfaults in case of bad addresses, which is a bit confusing: [How do I include Linux header files like linux/getcpu.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224607/how-do-i-include-linux-header-files-like-linux-getcpu-h/61774312#61774312) But it is not what the actual syscall does to the process, just whatever glibc is doing with that address.

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04, Linux 5.4.

Answer (score -1):

EFAULT is a macro defined in a file "include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h"

```
#define EFAULT          14      /* Bad address */
```