# reading from non-blocking named pipe gives EFAULT (14) in Ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, named-pipes, nonblocking

The code below returns EFAULT (errno == 14). I would appreciate help figuring out why.

I've also tried to implement the code using select() but still got the same error code.

I've got very similar code running on Python with no issues.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <errno.h> 



int read_fail1(int fd)
{
    int n;
    char buf[500];

    for (;;)
    {
        buf[strlen(buf)-1] = 0;
        n = read(fd, buf, strlen(buf)-1);
        
        if (n == -1)
        {
            if (errno == EFAULT)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "EFAULT");
                return 42;
            }
        }
        else if (n > 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s", buf);
        }

    }
}



int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    const char *myfifo = "pipeMUD";
  
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666); 
  
    int fd = open(myfifo, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);

    if (fd <= 0)
        return 42;

    read_fail1(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

POST ANSWER EDIT:

As mentioned in the post linked below, if an invalid address is passed to the kernel, it throws the EFAULT. I guess that on Linux, based on the above code, passing a 0 length count parameter to read() will also cause EFAULT to be retured.

[unix socket error 14: EFAULT (bad address)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260937/unix-socket-error-14-efault-bad-address)

Comment: `buf[strlen(buf)-1] = 0;` That's undefined behaviour as `buf` does not contain a valid string yet when it runs.

Comment:  can't believe I didn't see that. Sorry. Embarrassing

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile!  For instance, `int main(int argc, const char *argv[])` results in two warning messages about unused parameters. (suggest using: `int main( void )`.   When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings. ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pendantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results.

Comment: regarding: `n = read(fd, buf, strlen(buf)-1);` the function: `read()` returns a `ssize_t` not a `int`

Comment: regarding: `int fd = open(myfifo, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);`   since the posted code is only reading from the FIFO, should only open for reading, not writing

Comment: since the read is to a 'non-blocking' read(), suggest checking for `EAGAIN` when the returned byte count is 0

Comment: regarding `buf[strlen(buf)-1] = 0;
        n = read(fd, buf, strlen(buf)-1);`  It would be MUCH better to use: `ssize_t n = read( fd, buf, sizeof( buf )-1 );  If ( n > 0 ) { buf[ n ] = '\0'; } else if( n == 0 ) {  then no bytes available } else if( n<0 ) { /* handle error */ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
buf[strlen(buf)-1] = 0;
```

`buf` if a local variable, and thus is not initialized in C.
`strlen` looks for '\0' (null character) value, and thus will give unpredictable result on uninitialized array.

But, as long as you declare `buf` statically as you do, you can use `sizeof` instead.
Though it would be a better practice to use a macro instead:

```
#define READ_BUFFER_SIZE 500

char buf[READ_BUFFER_SIZE];
n = read(fd, buf, READ_BUFFER_SIZE - 1);
```

Comment: DUH  That was embarrassing. I looked at and tried everything except realizing my own silly mistake.